# Multiple ARRAYFORMULA inside each other (multi-level loop) in Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I may be going about this the wrong way, but what I would like to do is, essentially, create a loop to pull "Categories" and "Subcategories" into a single formula.

**Parents**

```
| Name     |
|----------|
| Cat 1    |
| Cat 2    |
| Cat 3    |
| Cat 4    |
|----------|
```

**Children**

```
| Name     |
|----------|
| Sub 1    |
| Sub 2    |
|----------|
```

Trying to achieve:

**Final Output (Option 1)**

```
| Name     | Child Of |
|----------|----------|
| Cat 1    |          |
| Sub 1    | Cat 1    |
| Sub 2    | Cat 1    |
| Cat 2    |          |
| Sub 1    | Cat 2    |
| Sub 2    | Cat 2    |
| Cat 3    |          |
| Sub 1    | Cat 3    |
| Sub 2    | Cat 3    |
| Cat 4    |          |
| Sub 1    | Cat 4    |
| Sub 2    | Cat 4    |
|----------|----------|
```

Or, **Final Output (Option 2)**

```
| Name     | Child Of |
|----------|----------|
| Cat 1    |          |
| Cat 2    |          |
| Cat 3    |          |
| Cat 4    |          |
| Sub 1    | Cat 1    |
| Sub 2    | Cat 1    |
| Sub 1    | Cat 2    |
| Sub 2    | Cat 2    |
| Sub 1    | Cat 3    |
| Sub 2    | Cat 3    |
| Sub 1    | Cat 4    |
| Sub 2    | Cat 4    |
|----------|----------|
```

I've tried concatenating `ARRAYFORMULA` as well as putting it inside itself, but it simply does not work. I'm not even sure how to search for this specific question (although I gave it my best shot in Google and SO and came up with nothing).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SPLIT({FILTER(A1:A, A1:A<>""); UNIQUE(
 TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(REPT(CONCATENATE(B1:B&CHAR(9)), COUNTA(A1:A)), CHAR(9)))&"♠"&
 TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(CONCATENATE(REPT(A1:A&CHAR(9), COUNTA(B1:B))), CHAR(9))))}, "♠"))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: @WesFoster based on this: https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/125018/186471 and just extended with FILTER and SPLIT by spade